# Python : Approaches to mine for time ordered sequences

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have a dataset that looks like this :

```
timestamp          event

12/1/2020 14:30     A  
12/1/2020 14:12     C
12/1/2020 14:10     A
12/1/2020 15:01     B
11/1/2020 21:20     A
11/1/2020 21:00     C
   .....           ...
```

`events` are actions by a user on an application. `timestamp` is when that particular event was raised.
I want to mine for sequences of events in the data to find out what a user's work-flow (market basket analysis with time constraint?) has been inside the application from the day user started using the application.

What I am trying to understand is what is the set of steps (events) the user performs most frequently.

ex: The output might be something like:

```
1 event sequence = {A}    # since it occurs the most number of times
2 event sequence = {A,C}  # since C is raised most number of times after A
3 event sequence = {} #event sequence of 3 steps that occurs most frequently
```

NOTE: Events occurring within a certain time frame (say, 20 minutes) can be considered to be a sequence of events.

...........................
What would the proper approach to solving this problem be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single event:

```
df.event.value_counts().head(1)
```

For multiple event:

```
from scipy import stats
from skimage.util import view_as_windows
event = df.event.values
for n in range(1,4):
  seq = view_as_windows(event,n).sum(-1)
  print(stats.mode(seq)[0])
```

output:

```
['A']
['AC']
['ABA']
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand this approach is finding out the frequent itemsets using a rolling window view (totally independent of the timestamp). Is there a possibility of doing the calculation in a time-dependent manner? ie [A, B, A] should not be a frequent sequence because of the difference between the time when they were raised in large...

Comment: @DevarshiGoswami You would then need to describe what sequence you define as a n-event sequence (in relation to timestamps). Otherwise, we will not know.

Comment: Where and how would you suggest I do that. Apologies for the naive questions, I'm a total noob.

Comment: @DevarshiGoswami you can edit your question to define a threshold and say for example, events in such time interval can be a sequence. There is a edit option below your post that allows you to edit it.